# Avoid Resources.NotFoundException in Android

Tags: android

Basically I need to create extract string resources and sometimes for locale there is no string resource available. Is there any way to get string or null if it is not found? I do not want to do try-catch every time it is missing

```
try {
    valuesForLocale.put(key, res.getString(key.id));
} catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
                //Ignore
}
```

Is there anything like `getStringOrNull()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [getIdentifier](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/content/res/Resources.html#getIdentifier(java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String)) method. The code without try-catch will look similar to:

```
int stringId = context.getResources().getIdentifier("my_resource_name", "string", mContext.getPackageName());

String text = (stringId != 0) ? context.getString(stringId) : "";
```

Comment: I think that would be even worse performance-wise than ignoring exception

Comment: I'm not sure about it. Resources.getIdentifier() uses AssetManager.getResourceIdentifier() method. If we look to the Android source code we'll see that it is native method. At least it doesn't use reflection )